# twig with Drupal 8: {% if content.field_ %} inconsistent results between two similar fields

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I have a content type (testnode) with two fields (field_one and field_two) defined the same way:

Structure > Content Type > Manage Fields:
Text (plain, long)

Structure > Content Type > Manage Fields> Field Settings >
Allowed number of values:  Limited, 1

Both field_one and field_two are set to "This is a test."

In the template (node--testnode--full.html.twig) I have the following:

```
     {% if content.field_one %}
            field_one: {{ content.field_one }}
      {% endif %}

     {% if content.field_two %}
            field_two: {{ content.field_two }}
      {% endif %}
```

The page only displays field_one, even though field_two is set to the same value:

field_one: This is a test.

What am I missing?

Comment: Verify the content of the variable(s) with `{{ dump(content.field_two) }}`

Comment: When I added {{ dump(content.field_two) }} the page displayed "NULL".  However, if I Edit the page the value is set.  Here is the relevant html from the Edit page:
<div class="form-textarea-wrapper">
  <textarea class="js-text-full text-full form-textarea resize-vertical" data-drupal-selector="edit-field-two-0-value" aria-describedby="edit-field-two-0-value--description" id="edit-field-two-0-value" name="field_two[0][value]" rows="5" cols="60" placeholder="">This is a test.</textarea>
</div>